# Find the latitude closest to a given location

Tags: r, raster, shapefile

```
library(dplyr)  
library(raster)

dat.shp <- getData('GADM', country='BRA', level = 1)
length(dat.shp@data$ID_1) # 27
```

I want to find for each admin `(ID_1)` which other ID_1's latitude is closest,

```
df <- data.frame(ID_1 = dat.shp@data$ID_1, lat = coordinates(dat.shp)[, 2])
df$closest.ID <- NA

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

  temp <- df[i, ]

  temp.dat <- df[-i, ] 

  sub <- temp.dat %>% dplyr::mutate(dif = lat - temp$lat) %>% 
         dplyr::filter(dif == min(dif))

  df[df$ID_1 == temp$ID_1, "closest.ID"] <- sub$ID_1

  rm(sub, temp.dat, temp)
}
```

This is obviously wrong since it gives me 21 for al lthe `ID_1`.

Comment: I don't see an `ID_1`, do you mean `GID_1`?

Comment: There is an `ID_1` field in the `dat.shp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with spatial data, it makes sense to lean on spatial libraries. There are many ways to accomplish this with `sp`, `rgeos`, `GISTools`, `raster`, `sf`, `stars`, etc. Here's one way with rgeos.

```
# spatial libraries
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

# get centroids of each polygon
c <- gCentroid(dat.shp, byid = TRUE)

# visualize
plot(dat.shp)
plot(c, add=T)
```

[image]

```
# make distance matrix of centroids
d <- gDistance(c, c, byid = TRUE)

# sort each column of the distance matrix
# the first value is zero: distance between a point and itself
# second value is the closest point != itself
# get the name of that point
closest_pts <- apply(d, 1, function(x){names(sort(x)[2])})

# make into a dataframe and view result
df <- data.frame(id = 1:length(dat.shp$ID_1), closest_pt = closest_pts)


> df

   id closest_pt
1   1          4
2   2         26
3   3         14
4   4         22
5   5         26
6   6         20
7   7          9
8   8         19
9   9          7
10 10         18
11 11         16
12 12          9
13 13          7
14 14          3
15 15         20
16 16         25
17 17         15
18 18         10
19 19          8
20 20         15
21 21         25
22 22          4
23 23          4
24 24         16
25 25         16
26 26          2
27 27          7
```

Comment: thank you. What If i want to create for each `id`,  all the other IDs in order of ascending/descending distance? i.e. for each id, list the 26 ids in order of their closeness?